# Decompile using dependencies

Tags: java, bukkit, decompiler

A project that I need to decompile uses an API that is a major part of the code. I know/have this API, is there any way to give it to a decompiler so objects from the API are used?

Example (using CFR decompiler):

```
Player sender = cmd.getSender();
Player target = cmd.getTarget();
World world = cmd.getWorld();
world.teleport(sender, target);
```

turns into:

```
Object obj1 = cmd.getSender();
Object obj2= cmd.getTarget();
Object obj3 = cmd.getWorld();
// cast must be added manually or error
(World) obj3.teleport(obj1, obj2);
```

Which is incredibly annoying considering the declaration and usage of a variable can be a hundred lines apart, and a method might use up to 20 different variables. I know you can't do anything about the names, but knowing the type would help incredibly.

Is there a way to fix this?
(I have no experience with decompilers, so I might be just dumb)

Comment: If I had to guess, this may be an issue with the original target method (e.g., `teleport`) containing generic parameters, but (1) the call site being stripped of any generic metadata; or (2) the invocation target could not be found in the class path, so the decompiler can't determine the method's true generic signature.  Alternatively, one or both may have been run through an obfuscator.  Without the original classfile(s), it's hard to tell.  My first suggestion would be to make sure any dependencies are in the decompiler's classpath.

Answer (score 0):

There is no decompiler which decompiles always without any error. Sometimes it decompiles well, sometimes not. The best way is to have several decompilers and use them each by other to decrease errors in decompiled source.
If you use Eclipse I would suggest this [plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enhanced-class-decompiler).
Or you can try this separate tool [Jar Explorer](http://dst.in.ua/jarexp/index.html?l=en). There are tree decompilers. So you can play with any one easily.